# got error in coding php...unexpected '['

Tags: php, function

I got error in my php code

this is my code

```
function cart() {
    foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
        if ($value>0) {
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'cart_'){
                $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
                $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id=' .mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    $sub = $get_row['price'] * $value;
                    echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ '.get_row['price'].' = '.$sub.'<br />' ;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "your cart is empty.";
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\shoppingcart\cart.php on line 39
```

which is

```
 echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ '.get_row['price'].' = '.$sub.'<br />' ;
```

I think my code is correct

please help me

I'm just a newbie in this field

thanks

Comment: Just an advice, you need only one escape here `mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id)`. if you are expecting an integer, use (int) casting only. if you are expecting string, use mysql_real_escape_string (or something else)

Comment: Why did the question get that much negative votes? In my opinion it shows research effort (analysing the error), is clear and useful (code snippets).

Answer (score 9):

Add the `$` sign to `get_row['price']`:

```
 echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ '.$get_row['price'].' = '.$sub.'<br />' ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
'.get_row['price'].'
```

The above code should be

```
'.$get_row['price'].'
```

It was missing the dollar symbol :)

Cheers

Gavin

Answer (score 2):

Change `get_row['price']` on `$get_row['price']`.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `$` before `get_row['price']`. Make it:

```
$get_row['price']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ '.`$`get_row['price'].' = '.$sub.'<br />' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$`:

Try  this:

```
echo $get_row['name'].' x '.$value.' @ '.$get_row['price'].' = '.$sub.'<br />' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better:

```
echo $get_row['name']." x ".$value." @ ".$get_row['price']." = ".$sub."<br />";
```